# Is it possible to disable logging in in the Terraria Hero's Mod?

Tags: terraria

Whenever I load a world with the Hero's Mod enabled, It forces you to 'log in'. How can I disable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone had asked if it's possible to disable logins on the mods forum page and the answer was ["not yet"](https://forums.terraria.org/index.php?threads/heros-mod-terraria-creative-mode-server-management-and-over-25-tools.44650/page-50#post-1715914).

Comment: has it been added yet? because i use the split screen mod and because of the mod it disables keyboard input on the client that uses the controller and i have no way to log in the other person or me for that matter but that's a me problem oh well